# mongoose response odd format

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

What I'm trying to do is let the user get a list of posts that they have added to their favorites which is done by simply putting their _id into the post's favorites array.

when running that particular query, it comes back as an array with unnamed entries along with _locals in the array.

I need something more like Posts: [ {}, {} ], _locals.

How do I get it into that format?

```html
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username  : String,
    firstName : String,
    lastName  : String,
    email     : String,
    password  : String
});

var PostSchema = new Schema({
    author    : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    date      : Date,
    body     : String,
    username  : String,
    sid       : String,
    views     : Number,
    likes     : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    favorites : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});

and the get

app.get('/favorites', function(req, res) {
  Post
  .find({ 'favorites': '58f4f9e5650785228016287f'})
  .exec(function(err, favorites) {
    res.render('favorites', favorites)
    console.log(favorites)
  })
});

I get a response of 
[ { _id: 58f4f9e96507852280162880,
    author: 58f4f9e5650785228016287f,
    body: 'test',
    date: 2017-04-17T17:22:49.059Z,
    username: 'test',
    sid: 'BJ-xquGRl',
    __v: 2,
    favorites: [ 58f4f9e5650785228016287f ],
    likes: [] },
  { _id: 58f500edd8abc7242c90d61c,
    author: 58f4f9e5650785228016287f,
    body: 'w00p w00p',
    date: 2017-04-17T17:52:45.612Z,
    username: 'test',
    sid: 'BJ8g-tG0e',
    __v: 1,
    favorites: [ 58f4f9e5650785228016287f ],
    likes: [] },
  _locals: { user:
     { id: 58f4f9e5650785228016287f,
       username: 'test',
       firstName: 'test',
       lastName: 'test',
       email: 'test@test.com' } } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `_locals` is something that Express adds to the object that you pass to `res.render()`. If you would reverse the function calls you made, it wouldn't be there anymore:

```
console.log(favorites);
res.render('favorites', favorites);
```

However, the main issue is that you're passing an array (`favorites`) as argument to `res.render()`, which expects an object instead. The correct way of calling it would be by passing `favorites` as an object value:

```
res.render('favorites', { favorites : favorites });
// Or in recent Node versions:
// res.render('favorites', { favorites });
```